# Using org.json.JSONObject and Jackson together

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
public String convertToJson(List<MyModelDTO> modelDTO) {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(modelDTO);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public Model getDefinition(ModelDTO modelDTO) {
    JsonAjaxModel jsonAjaxModel = new JsonAjaxModel();

    //resultMap is a map to initialise the JSON
    org.json.JSONObject modelStepsJson = new JSONObject(resultMap);
    org.json.JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("MODELLING_STEPS", modelStepsJson);

    List<MyModelDTO> methodModelList = myDAO.getSavedsteps(MyModelDTO.getModelId());
    jsonObj.put("STEPS", convertToJson(methodModelList));

    jsonAjaxModel.setJsonString(jsonObj.toString());
    return jsonAjaxModel;
}
```

As seen above I am using Jackson with `org.json.JSONObject`. The problem is that the final JSON string generated has '' in it which is giving an error while using eval in JavaScript.

```json
{"MODELLING_STEPS":{
    "1":"Data Set,UOM and modelling methodology Selection",
    "2":"Loss Data Frequency modelling"},
"STEPS":"[
    {\\\"stitchingModelId\\\":200844,\\\"modellingStepId\\\":1},
    {\\\"stitchingModelId\\\":200844,\\\"modellingStepId\\\":2}
]
```

Please note that I cannot use `org.json.simple.JSONObject.escape()` as my project doesn't allow that.

Hope the question is clear. Please let me know how to escape ''.

Answer (score 1):

I propose not to convert the jsonObj object to a String object. And therefore to replace the line:

```
jsonAjaxModel.setJsonString(jsonObj.toString ())
```

by a function like:

```
jsonAjaxModel.setJsonObj(jsonObj);
```

Comment: If you can't change the class JsonAjaxModel; Can you extend this class with opportunities for legacy JAVA? If yes then you can try the solution that I have presented above.

Comment: I am surprised to see so far that there is actually no solution to this. These are more like workaround, last option to do. Is there any way to use the two APIs together?